# how do i open input file through patran using start with /wait command

Tags: perl

Am using perl to open an .exe file and following is my command

```
start /wait  C:/Software/Patran_x64/20170/bin/patran.exe D:\Application_Integration_Files\Patran\toPreProcessor.ses
```

This command opens the application but not opening the input file that i have provided as a second parameter and it will hold the command till i close the application.

And the following command opens the application with the input file but it is not holding the command in the command prompt till i close the application.
Here is the command

```
start /wait  "C:/Software/Patran_x64/20170/bin/patran.exe" "D:\Application_Integration_Files\Patran\toPreProcessor.ses"
```

The only difference between both the command is double quotes (""), i want the output like, it should open the application with the input file given and as well as it should hold the command till i close the application (Am using /wait switch to hold the command)

This is my `Perl` Script

```
    my $cadfix1="C:/Software/Patran_x64/20170/bin/patran.exe";
    my $cadfix2="D:/Application_Integration_Files/Patran/toPreProcessor.ses";
    my $path1 ="start /wait "." " ."$cadfix1" . " " ."$cadfix2"."";
   #my $path2="start /wait \"$cadfix1\" \"$cadfix2\"";
    system($path1);
```

$path1 and $path2 refers to first and second command as mentioned above.

Please anyone help me with this thank you :)

Comment: Did you add all those tags just to get more exposure for your question?

Comment: I removed unwanted tags. Please also explain how your are running these commands from `perl` because nothing in this code is perl.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, i have added perl script that i have for running the application please give me the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If you want output, you need to rather use backticks.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $command = '"C:/Software/Patran_x64/20170/bin/patran.exe"';
my $cadfix2 = '"D:/Application_Integration_Files/Patran/toPreProcessor.ses"';
my $path1 = `$command $cadfix2`;
```

I am also not certain why you want to use perl for something so simple, you could just run a batchfile.

Should you want to keep the file window open, then run last line as:

```
my $path1 = `cmd /k $command $cadfix2`;
```

Comment: There is another reason why i am using Perl, you suggest me in batch script, i will refer the same logic in perl

Comment: @PradeepYenkuwale Then just try what I have posted.